# Vue js how to use props values to v-model

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have two component namely **App.vue** and **hello.vue**

In **App** component I import the **hello** component and use props to pass relevant data to the **hello** component.
there I bind data which are took from the **App** component.

In my hello component I have a `input box` bind to the passed value.

My final goal is pass values as props to the **hello** component and change it and finally
pass that edited values to the backend using the save method.

How do I achive this?

This is what I have done up to now.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <hello-world :msg="'hello good morning'"></hello-world>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import helloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";
export default {
  components: {
    helloWorld
  }
};
</script>
```

**hello.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" :value="msg">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
};
</script>
```

In my hello component's input field v-model is not possible. I want something similar to the v-model.

Comment: All the information you need is right [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `prop` to bind to `v-model`. Child component is not supposed to modify `prop` passed by the parent component.

You will have to create a copy of `prop` in your child component if you wish to use `prop` with `v-model` and then watch `prop` like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="text" @input="onInput" v-model="msgCopy">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "HelloWorld",
    props: {
        msg: String
    },

    data() {
        return { msgCopy: '' };
    },

    methods: {
        onInput(newInputValue) {
            this.$emit('msgChange', newInputValue);
        }
    }

    watch: {
        msg(newVal) {
            this.msgCopy = newVal;
        }
    }

};
</script>
```

Also, notice the use of event handler `@input` to pass changed `prop` back to the parent component via event. As a syntax sugar, you can make your `Hello` component work as a custom form input control by adopting to `v-model` lifecycle.